# Binding on a method?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This is kinda hard to define my question precisely but I'll try to do my best !
I actually have a lots (hundreds) of classical Bindings like this :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FrameNames}"/>
```

Where FrameNames is a properties of my code-behind.
The thing is that I, now, have to do a binding on a method and I know that this is not the MVVM norm but that's what I want to do.
The code (that doesn't work) look like :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LocalizationUtil.GetLocales()}"/>
```

Is there a way to do it ? (even if this is not prely respecting the MVVM pattern !)

(This work if I do it in the code-behind, MyComboBox.Itemsource = LocalizationUtil.GetLocales()
but of course it doesn't get noticed if there is a change)

Comment: What do you want to achive? If it is UI localization (as I guess from the Names) there are easier/better ways...

Comment: This is just a combox with string that are the available locales (like "en-GN" "en-US" etcetc..). Just a ComboBox with Strings, nothing more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `Locales` property to your view model and bind to it, like so

```
public LocaleObject Locales
{
    get { return LocalizationUtil.GetLocales(); }
}

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Locales, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Yeah, but this a public property :/

Comment: Why don't you want a public property?  A property with only a public getter gives access to only as much as the method would.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but it is kind of a pain.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348824.aspx

Comment: Useful if you want to make a generally accessible resource.

Comment: Yeah, the question was a lot more vague when I answered it.

Comment: I was even thinking of something that may need parameters...  but I guess you could do some indexing type hack if you wanted.

Comment: I've seen it used to enumerate system colors.